# In Python how to calculate width implied by format specifier containing fixed format items

Tags: python, regex, string-formatting

I have got a format specifier in Python which contains only fixed width format items, and I want to use it to calculate a length so that I can write a line of `=` characters of the correct length to line up with the formatted data.

Here is my code. I am turning letters into numbers and adding them up, but I'm okay with that bit. The problem is working out how many `=` characters to write based on the format string, basically function `get_width` that I want to write.  In my code I have commented out the call and hard coded the answer `9` for the format string `"{:>5s} {:3d}"`.

```
fmt = "{:>5s} {:3d}"

#width = get_width(fmt)  # <= THE BIT I NEED HELP WITH
width = 9   # <= HARD CODED THE ANSWER

sentence = "The name is Boris d.P. Johnson and now we are going to calculate the number."
total = 0
for c in sentence:
    number = ord(c.lower()) - ord("a") + 1 if c.isalpha() else 0
    print(fmt.format(c, number))  # <= FORMATTED DATA
    total += number
print("=" * width)  # <= NEED THE RIGHT WIDTH
print(fmt.format("TOTAL", total))    # <= FORMATTED DATA
print("=" * width)  # <= HERE AGAIN
```

To show you what I am trying to achieve, here are the last few lines of the output and you can see that the line of `=` is the correct width to go with the formatted data, but that is because I hard-coded the answer.

```
    n  14
    u  21
    m  13
    b   2
    e   5
    r  18
    .   0
=========
TOTAL 666
=========
```

**What I have tried**

If you *know* that `fmt` will be used to format a string and an integer, then of course you can just use it to format a dummy data item, for example:

```
def get_width(fmt):
    return(len(fmt.format("", 0)))
```

but this is not very general. There doesn't seem to be a generic way to do this without having to know the number and type of arguments, for example if you have the wrong type or not enough arguments then it will give an error so you can't just do `len(fmt.format())` for example.

Not sure if I need to do some kind of parsing of the format string myself. That is going to be awkward, for example you might have digits in the format string that are not inside any `{}` bits, and these would just appear as literals in the formatted output, so it is not just a case of pulling out the digits using a simple `re.findall("\d+", fmt)` then converting to int and adding them up.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: You are overthinking this. The easiest and most common way is to just figure out what you are going to print, take the length of that, and caculate the needed width.

Comment: So do i understand you right, that print("=" * len((fmt.format("TOTAL", total)))) is what you want to avoid?

Comment: But I want to use the format string as the input so that if I change it then I don't need to also change the width. Also I would like to have a generic `get_width` function that I can import into my program, so it has to not depend on being told explicitly about the data types, it has to accept the format string as the sole input and return a width. Obviously I understand that this depends on there not being any variable width items.

Comment: Jonas yes that's right, I am wondering if there is a way to get the width just from `fmt` itself. So you can use it in some more generic situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just recalculate the width as part of the output.

Example.

Here is a function that will encapsulate what you might think is repetitive:

```
def over_and_under(fmt,*args):
    output=fmt.format(*args)
    width=len(output)
    print('-'*width)
    print(output)
    print('='*width)
```

But it is really quite flexible just like that. It will take any format specifier with a variable number of arguments and correctly overline and underline its output.

```
>>> over_and_under("{:>5s} {}{:,.2f}", 'Total:', '$', 92456)
-----------------
Total: $92,456.00
=================
```

Now if you tried to *calculate* the result of that format without just using `format`, well that is going to be a lot of work. In this case you would have to parse the `:,.2` and that is just to get started.

If you potentially have a `\t` in the format, just expand the tab as part of the calculation:

```
def over_and_under(fmt,*args):
    output=fmt.format(*args).expandtabs()
    width=len(output)
    print('-'*width)
    print(output)
    print('='*width)

>>> over_and_under('{}:\t{}','Bob Smith','CEO') 
-------------------
Bob Smith:      CEO
===================
```

Comment: Sure you can work around it like that but I was hoping there might be a way to get the width just from `fmt` without knowing what types of data items you want to format it with. (Apart from the information that is _contained_ inside the string itself, i.e. not an argument list.)

Comment: The other way to do it is to subclass the formatter and add the functionality. It is not native. Subclassing the formatter class is covered in [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)